# H1b visa leave of absence for contract of professional basketball in France

Tags: visa, h1-visa

I'm from Benin in Africa. I have my h1b visa but before that I signed a two year contract to play professional basketball in France and already completed one year. But I have to complete the second year to not have to pay the team the whole year if contract I also don't want to lose my H1B. My company is willing to give me a 10month leave of absence. Will I have problems to come back to the states if I choose to play that last year?